# Multiple Forms in one JSP file interacting with Different Servlets

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp, servlets

I have a `index.jsp` file that has two different types of forms

```
<form action="searchpath" name="searchForm" method="get">
<p>BedType</p>
   <select name="bedType">
     <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/embeds/bedType.jsp"/>
   </select>
   <p>Max Price</p>
     <input size="10" maxlength="10" name="mPrice"/>
     <br/><br/>
     <input name="Reset" type="reset" value="RESET" class="input"/> <input type="submit" class="input" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
```

and

```
    <form action="loginController" method="post" id="loginForm">
        Please Login :<input name="username" size="30" maxlength="30"/> 
        Password : <input name="pass" type="password" size="30" maxlength="30"/>    
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="input"/>
    </form>
```

I thought that the `action` field type directed to the `web.xml` `<url-pattern>/searchpath</url-pattern>` would allow me to direct whatever input information I place in those forms to the servlet of that path. That is, the first form will interact with my `searchpath` servlet. When I tried submitting a form and printing out information nothing seemed to work and I kept receiving a `http 404 error` . Can someone please help me out with this?

web.xml :

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Search</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/searchpath</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

inside my search.java servlet :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<HTML>");
    out.println("<HEAD>");
    out.println("<TITLE>Static Servlet</TITLE>");
    out.println("</HEAD>");
    out.println("<BODY>");
    out.println("<h1>WTF</h1>");
        out.println("</BODY>");
    out.println("</HTML>");
```

Comment: Add the context path in the `action` attribute of `form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check browser URL. You are missing context.

Let Say, You are running at http://localhost:8080/test/index.jsp where `test` is your context path.

So, When calling Servlet It should be like http://localhost:8080/test/searchpath.

In your case, Its not like that.

So, Adding cotextpath will solve your problem.

e.g. `action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/searchpath"`